# Fixed table header inside a scrollable div

Tags: html, css, gridstack

First of all, there are indeed multiple similar questions but they are not working in my case. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827908/how-to-make-fixed-header-table-inside-scrollable-div), [Other related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320837/fixed-header-in-table-inside-scrollable-div)

---

The structure is like `page > div > div > stuff + table`

I am using [Gridstack.js](https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/) and here is my current code

```js
$('.grid-stack').gridstack();
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.2.6/gridstack.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.2.6/gridstack.min.js'></script>

<body>
  <div class="grid-stack">
    <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="10" data-gs-height="2">
      <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Button A</button>
          <button>Button B</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a>Link A</a>
          <a>Link B</a>
        </div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ColA</th>
              <th>ColB</th>
              <th>ColC</th>
              <th>ColD</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Mauritius</td>
              <td>Castor</td>
              <td>F14 3QF</td>
              <td>dignissim.pharetra@aliquetmolestietellus.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Guyana</td>
              <td>Inuvik</td>
              <td>67752</td>
              <td>Nam.porttitor@sitamet.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Norfolk Island</td>
              <td>Sparwood</td>
              <td>10899-987</td>
              <td>in.consectetuer@ametmetusAliquam.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Afghanistan</td>
              <td>Sant'Urbano</td>
              <td>7142</td>
              <td>lectus.convallis@ornareIn.co.uk</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Macao</td>
              <td>Bon Accord</td>
              <td>16-568</td>
              <td>auctor.velit.Aliquam@consectetuerrhoncus.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Philippines</td>
              <td>Anghiari</td>
              <td>280294</td>
              <td>neque.vitae@eu.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Bangladesh</td>
              <td>Falciano del Massico</td>
              <td>90856</td>
              <td>id@vitae.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Micronesia</td>
              <td>Divinópolis</td>
              <td>45-520</td>
              <td>scelerisque.neque@vitaesemper.co.uk</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Antigua and Barbuda</td>
              <td>Dudzele</td>
              <td>728363</td>
              <td>dignissim.tempor.arcu@vulputate.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Papua New Guinea</td>
              <td>Joué-lès-Tours</td>
              <td>958173</td>
              <td>amet@eleifendnondapibus.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Hong Kong</td>
              <td>Gateshead</td>
              <td>83548-761</td>
              <td>fringilla.purus@enimnec.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Iran</td>
              <td>Minto</td>
              <td>80622</td>
              <td>adipiscing.ligula@fringillaDonec.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Curaçao</td>
              <td>Whitby</td>
              <td>59472</td>
              <td>ante@anteNunc.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Korea, South</td>
              <td>Montpelier</td>
              <td>L8 2TT</td>
              <td>a@sagittisDuisgravida.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Papua New Guinea</td>
              <td>Dokkum</td>
              <td>205204</td>
              <td>sed.libero@convallisest.co.uk</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>New Zealand</td>
              <td>Maisires</td>
              <td>9279</td>
              <td>ultrices.posuere.cubilia@sem.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Panama</td>
              <td>Rankweil</td>
              <td>30910</td>
              <td>elit.fermentum@odio.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>New Zealand</td>
              <td>Melsele</td>
              <td>23428</td>
              <td>sed.libero.Proin@nequevitaesemper.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cuba</td>
              <td>Wolvertem</td>
              <td>93687-468</td>
              <td>auctor.odio@pellentesqueafacilisis.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Indonesia</td>
              <td>Rothesay</td>
              <td>919761</td>
              <td>augue.scelerisque@asollicitudin.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Japan</td>
              <td>Inuvik</td>
              <td>2899</td>
              <td>massa.non@ligulaDonecluctus.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mauritius</td>
              <td>Zeitz</td>
              <td>603912</td>
              <td>consequat@diamPellentesquehabitant.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Curaçao</td>
              <td>Lincoln</td>
              <td>11148</td>
              <td>tristique.neque@Nullamlobortis.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Swaziland</td>
              <td>Newtown</td>
              <td>9616</td>
              <td>ipsum@sapien.ca</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Brazil</td>
              <td>Rodì Milici</td>
              <td>861316</td>
              <td>fames@variusultricesmauris.ca</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

## Current behavior

While scrolling inside the `div` there is nothing special, you will first scroll thought the `input`, `links`,... then though the table

## Expected behavior

While scrolling, when the header hits the top of the `div` - the header should be fixed on the top of the `div` (Not the top of the page). When scrolled back, the header should go back to its normal state.

There is no need to check for the end of the div to hide the header. The end of the div will always be the end of the table.

---

How can this be achieved ? The header should not be fixed to the top of the page but the top of the `div`

***Note: this should work for IE11 also***

Answer (score 2):

Add style for your table

```
table thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
  background: RED;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

[support of sticky](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky)

```js
$('.grid-stack').gridstack();
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
    background: RED;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.2.6/gridstack.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.2.6/gridstack.min.js'></script>

<body>
  <div class="grid-stack">
    <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="10" data-gs-height="2">
      <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Button A</button>
          <button>Button B</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a>Link A</a>
          <a>Link B</a>
        </div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ColA</th>
              <th>ColB</th>
              <th>ColC</th>
              <th>ColD</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Mauritius</td>
              <td>Castor</td>
              <td>F14 3QF</td>
              <td>dignissim.pharetra@aliquetmolestietellus.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Guyana</td>
              <td>Inuvik</td>
              <td>67752</td>
              <td>Nam.porttitor@sitamet.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Norfolk Island</td>
              <td>Sparwood</td>
              <td>10899-987</td>
              <td>in.consectetuer@ametmetusAliquam.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Afghanistan</td>
              <td>Sant'Urbano</td>
              <td>7142</td>
              <td>lectus.convallis@ornareIn.co.uk</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Macao</td>
              <td>Bon Accord</td>
              <td>16-568</td>
              <td>auctor.velit.Aliquam@consectetuerrhoncus.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Philippines</td>
              <td>Anghiari</td>
              <td>280294</td>
              <td>neque.vitae@eu.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Bangladesh</td>
              <td>Falciano del Massico</td>
              <td>90856</td>
              <td>id@vitae.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Micronesia</td>
              <td>Divinópolis</td>
              <td>45-520</td>
              <td>scelerisque.neque@vitaesemper.co.uk</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Antigua and Barbuda</td>
              <td>Dudzele</td>
              <td>728363</td>
              <td>dignissim.tempor.arcu@vulputate.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Papua New Guinea</td>
              <td>Joué-lès-Tours</td>
              <td>958173</td>
              <td>amet@eleifendnondapibus.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Hong Kong</td>
              <td>Gateshead</td>
              <td>83548-761</td>
              <td>fringilla.purus@enimnec.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Iran</td>
              <td>Minto</td>
              <td>80622</td>
              <td>adipiscing.ligula@fringillaDonec.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Curaçao</td>
              <td>Whitby</td>
              <td>59472</td>
              <td>ante@anteNunc.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Korea, South</td>
              <td>Montpelier</td>
              <td>L8 2TT</td>
              <td>a@sagittisDuisgravida.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Papua New Guinea</td>
              <td>Dokkum</td>
              <td>205204</td>
              <td>sed.libero@convallisest.co.uk</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>New Zealand</td>
              <td>Maisires</td>
              <td>9279</td>
              <td>ultrices.posuere.cubilia@sem.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Panama</td>
              <td>Rankweil</td>
              <td>30910</td>
              <td>elit.fermentum@odio.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>New Zealand</td>
              <td>Melsele</td>
              <td>23428</td>
              <td>sed.libero.Proin@nequevitaesemper.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cuba</td>
              <td>Wolvertem</td>
              <td>93687-468</td>
              <td>auctor.odio@pellentesqueafacilisis.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Indonesia</td>
              <td>Rothesay</td>
              <td>919761</td>
              <td>augue.scelerisque@asollicitudin.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Japan</td>
              <td>Inuvik</td>
              <td>2899</td>
              <td>massa.non@ligulaDonecluctus.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mauritius</td>
              <td>Zeitz</td>
              <td>603912</td>
              <td>consequat@diamPellentesquehabitant.edu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Curaçao</td>
              <td>Lincoln</td>
              <td>11148</td>
              <td>tristique.neque@Nullamlobortis.org</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Swaziland</td>
              <td>Newtown</td>
              <td>9616</td>
              <td>ipsum@sapien.ca</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Brazil</td>
              <td>Rodì Milici</td>
              <td>861316</td>
              <td>fames@variusultricesmauris.ca</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it is close from working. The problem is that it should work on IE11. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: @Weedoze, only position absolute || fixed  +  js

Comment: Any hints on how to do it ?

Comment: @Weedoze, there are many solutions ([1](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders), [2](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/), http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1362/ and others), try them.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with CSS `position: fixed` and jQuery script. Check out the snippet below or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wecfbsk/).

```js
$('.grid-stack').gridstack();

$('thead th').each(function(index) {
  $('.fixed-header th').eq(index).css('width', $(this).width());
});
$('.fixed-header-container').height($('.fixed-header').height());
$('.fixed-header-container').hide();

$('.grid-stack-item-content').scroll(function() {
  var $table = $('.content-table');

  if ($table.offset().top >= 0) {
    $('.fixed-header-container').hide();
  } else if ($table.offset().top < 0) {
    $('.fixed-header-container').show();
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.2.6/gridstack.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.2.6/gridstack.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="grid-stack">
  <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="10" data-gs-height="2">
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content fixed-header-container" style="z-index: 1 !important;">
      <table class="fixed-header">
        <tr>
          <th>ColA</th>
          <th>ColB</th>
          <th>ColC</th>
          <th>ColD</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
      <div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <input type="text">
        <div>
          <button>Button A</button>
          <button>Button B</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a>Link A</a>
          <a>Link B</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="content-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ColA</th>
            <th>ColB</th>
            <th>ColC</th>
            <th>ColD</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Mauritius</td>
            <td>Castor</td>
            <td>F14 3QF</td>
            <td>dignissim.pharetra@aliquetmolestietellus.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Guyana</td>
            <td>Inuvik</td>
            <td>67752</td>
            <td>Nam.porttitor@sitamet.edu</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Norfolk Island</td>
            <td>Sparwood</td>
            <td>10899-987</td>
            <td>in.consectetuer@ametmetusAliquam.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Afghanistan</td>
            <td>Sant'Urbano</td>
            <td>7142</td>
            <td>lectus.convallis@ornareIn.co.uk</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Macao</td>
            <td>Bon Accord</td>
            <td>16-568</td>
            <td>auctor.velit.Aliquam@consectetuerrhoncus.edu</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Philippines</td>
            <td>Anghiari</td>
            <td>280294</td>
            <td>neque.vitae@eu.org</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bangladesh</td>
            <td>Falciano del Massico</td>
            <td>90856</td>
            <td>id@vitae.edu</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Micronesia</td>
            <td>Divinópolis</td>
            <td>45-520</td>
            <td>scelerisque.neque@vitaesemper.co.uk</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Antigua and Barbuda</td>
            <td>Dudzele</td>
            <td>728363</td>
            <td>dignissim.tempor.arcu@vulputate.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Papua New Guinea</td>
            <td>Joué-lès-Tours</td>
            <td>958173</td>
            <td>amet@eleifendnondapibus.net</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hong Kong</td>
            <td>Gateshead</td>
            <td>83548-761</td>
            <td>fringilla.purus@enimnec.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Iran</td>
            <td>Minto</td>
            <td>80622</td>
            <td>adipiscing.ligula@fringillaDonec.edu</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Curaçao</td>
            <td>Whitby</td>
            <td>59472</td>
            <td>ante@anteNunc.org</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Korea, South</td>
            <td>Montpelier</td>
            <td>L8 2TT</td>
            <td>a@sagittisDuisgravida.org</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Papua New Guinea</td>
            <td>Dokkum</td>
            <td>205204</td>
            <td>sed.libero@convallisest.co.uk</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>New Zealand</td>
            <td>Maisires</td>
            <td>9279</td>
            <td>ultrices.posuere.cubilia@sem.org</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Panama</td>
            <td>Rankweil</td>
            <td>30910</td>
            <td>elit.fermentum@odio.org</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>New Zealand</td>
            <td>Melsele</td>
            <td>23428</td>
            <td>sed.libero.Proin@nequevitaesemper.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cuba</td>
            <td>Wolvertem</td>
            <td>93687-468</td>
            <td>auctor.odio@pellentesqueafacilisis.edu</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Indonesia</td>
            <td>Rothesay</td>
            <td>919761</td>
            <td>augue.scelerisque@asollicitudin.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Japan</td>
            <td>Inuvik</td>
            <td>2899</td>
            <td>massa.non@ligulaDonecluctus.org</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mauritius</td>
            <td>Zeitz</td>
            <td>603912</td>
            <td>consequat@diamPellentesquehabitant.edu</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Curaçao</td>
            <td>Lincoln</td>
            <td>11148</td>
            <td>tristique.neque@Nullamlobortis.org</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Swaziland</td>
            <td>Newtown</td>
            <td>9616</td>
            <td>ipsum@sapien.ca</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brazil</td>
            <td>Rodì Milici</td>
            <td>861316</td>
            <td>fames@variusultricesmauris.ca</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not doing what I need. I need to have the header of the table fixed on the top.. Not the inputs,links,buttons,... + The width is larger when fixed

Comment: @Weedoze I misunderstood your question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This is not working in my code.. I am trying to figure out why

Comment: Still not working. For the moment, I am using `position:sticky`. If this need to be used on IE, I will try another way